# Snubber design for a relay that controls a 30W AC fan

Tags: relay, snubber, arc

I am trying to switch a 30W, 230V AC fan and a LED strip with an Arduino from D11 and D12 pins. In my previous experience, the  EMI generated while turning off the fan bricked my project within months and now I am being extra cautious.

[image: Schematic]

There are three snubbers in this circuit. None of them compliments to fast switching like SMPS and they are only protecting devices that are occasionally turned on/off. I've calculated all snubbers with the same formula:

**1.** I've guessed inductances of the relay coil, fan coil and LED strip. I do not have the necessary equipment to measure real L and it's not written in the datasheet. I assumed 100mH for the relay coil, 400mH for the fan coil,  and 50uH for the LED strip. I measured DC resistance of fan as 120 ohms by putting probes on line and neutral pins, if that helps.

**2.** The maximum LED strip current is 3A andthe  relay coil current is 16.7mA. I calculated peak fan current by ignoring the unknown power factor as below:

- I_Fan_RMS = P_Fan/V_RMS = 30W/230V = 0.13A
- I_Fan_peak = I_Fan_RMS * sqrt(2) = 0.185A

**3)** I calculated the energy that the inductors store by "E = 1/2 * L * I_peak^2".

**4)** From the capacitor energy formula I know "C_snub = 2 * Energy/V_max^2". The dielectric strength between relay contacts were given as 1000VAC in the datasheet thus, I aimed for 750V V_max with safety margin.  I chose 25V V_max for the IRF2804 40V MOSFET. For the rest of the calculation I'll only focus on fan coil snubber to reduce complexity. C_snub = 2 * 0.0068/750^2 = 24nF".

**5.** I had very little idea for choosing R_snub thus I randomly chose 220R. I need help on this.

**6.** The varistor works as a backup plan. It is to clamp the voltage to 845V if the RC snubber fails to prevent spikes.

**Q1)** Are the above steps the correct way to design a snubber?

**Q2)** I don't want to waste energy during off time but a snubber on the contacts creates a current path. That's why I've only put a 10nF cap across the contacts and I will add additional RC snubber (C = 22nF) between the line and neutral connections of the fan. Is this a good practice? What could be the disadvantages?

**Q3)** The Arduino is 3.3V and lacks strong gate drive. I also wanted some isolation from the gates of the MOSFETs, so I used a TC4427. Have I used the IC correctly? I haven't used complimentary components besides bypass capacitors.

**Q4)** C8 and R18 might seem unnecessary when D3 is there, but I known that diodes need some time to start conducting so I've added theRC. Actually, the diode might be acting as a capacitor before it starts to conduct so maybe the RC is unnecessary. I need comments on this please.

Links: [HF46F datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/312374/HONGFA/HF46F.html), [TC4427 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001422G.pdf), [Varistor datasheet](https://pdf.direnc.net/upload/320vac-510vdc-14mm-varistor-14d511-datasheet.pdf), no datasheet for the fan.

Comment: Why not use a relay driver chip?  It would replace the mosfet driver, the mosfets themselves, and the diodes.  And what was the original design that burned up?

Comment: I didn't use relay driver because this is such a simple load. My main concern is about AC side (Snubber for fan inductance). The old design died and I guess it was because of the arcs happening in the relay (sometimes they were visible). I didn't use any snubber back then.

Comment: It looks like you've given this some thought, and *in my opinion* it should reduce peak voltages,  but I'd replace the SS24 Schottky diode with a 30 V or so *Zener* diode, to provide protection in the *forward* direction from the relay's inductive kick. BTW, even though there was visible arcing at the relay contacts, which as you state should be suppressed, I believe the inductive kick of the coil did the damage. Make sure there is no capacitive coupling between fan and control: i.e., keep leads separated and ground the chassis.